# Dynamically defined variable in ABAP

Tags: abap, netweaver

Lets say I have a variable (char30) which contains a name of a Datatype and I would like to create another variable of this Datatype.

Example:

```
lv_type = 'BU_PARTNER'
data: rt_value type range of ( lv_type ).
```

Any tips how to achieve this in ABAP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RANGE` table is just a `STANDARD` table with component like `'LOW', 'HIGH', 'EQ' and 'OPTION'`.

Using [RTTS](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenrtti.htm) related API to create such a `STANDARD` table.

```
data:
    lr_data          type ref to data,
    lt_ra_string     type range of string,
    ls_ra_string     like line of lt_ra_string,
    ls_component     type line of abap_component_tab,
    lt_component    type abap_component_tab,
    lt_ra_components type abap_component_tab,
    lo_struc_descr type ref to cl_abap_structdescr,
    lo_table_descr type ref to cl_abap_tabledescr,
    lo_data_descr  type ref to cl_abap_datadescr.

field-symbols:
    <lv_value> type any,
    <lt_ra_type> type standard table,
    <ls_ra_type> type any.

    data(lv_type) = 'BU_PARTNER'.

create data lr_data type (lv_type).

lo_struc_descr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_data( p_data = ls_ra_string ).

lt_component = lo_struc_descr->get_components( ).

lo_data_descr ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>describe_by_name( lv_type ).

lt_ra_components = value #( for comp in lt_component (
                            name = comp-name
                            type = cond #( 
                                when comp-name eq 'SIGN' 
                                  or comp-name eq 'OPTION'
                                then  comp-type
                                else lo_data_descr )
                        ) ).
lo_struc_descr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>create( lt_ra_components ).
lo_table_descr ?= cl_abap_tabledescr=>create( lo_struc_descr ).

create data lr_data type handle lo_table_descr.
assign lr_data->* to <lt_ra_type>.

create data lr_data like line of <lt_ra_type>.
assign lr_data->* to <ls_ra_type>.

assign component 'SIGN' of structure <ls_ra_type> to <lv_value>.
<lv_value> = 'I'.
assign component 'OPTION' of structure <ls_ra_type> to <lv_value>.
<lv_value> = 'EQ'.
assign component 'LOW' of structure <ls_ra_type> to <lv_value>.
<lv_value> = 'DUMMY1'.
assign component 'HIGH' of structure <ls_ra_type> to <lv_value>.
<lv_value> = 'DUMMY2'.

* <lt_ra_type> is your range table
append <ls_ra_type> to <lt_ra_type>.
```

Answer (score 1):

A range data type is nothing but a structure with four fields :

Sign 
Option
Low
High

So you can use RTTS to build such a structure dynamically since the data types for sign and option are fixed and the ones for 'low" and "high" you can set dynamically . Then once you have the structure object reference, you can assign it to a field symbol.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no built-in command for creating range tables dynamically. You have to use [RTTC](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenrtti.htm) to build up the range table:

```
TYPE-POOLS: abap.

DATA:
  g_dataelement     TYPE rollname,
  go_structdescr    TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
  go_tabledescr     TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr,
  gt_component      TYPE abap_component_tab,
  gs_component      TYPE LINE OF abap_component_tab,
  gr_range          TYPE REF TO data,
  gr_range_line     TYPE REF TO data.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <gs_range_line> TYPE any,
               <gs_range> TYPE table.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  g_dataelement = 'BU_PARTNER'.

  " Create component table
  gs_component-name = 'SIGN'.
  gs_component-type ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>get_c( 1 ).
  INSERT gs_component INTO TABLE gt_component.
  gs_component-name = 'OPTION'.
  gs_component-type ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>get_c( 2 ).
  INSERT gs_component INTO TABLE gt_component.
  gs_component-name = 'LOW'.
  gs_component-type ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>describe_by_name( g_dataelement ).
  INSERT gs_component INTO TABLE gt_component.
  gs_component-name = 'HIGH'.
  gs_component-type ?= cl_abap_elemdescr=>describe_by_name( g_dataelement ).
  INSERT gs_component INTO TABLE gt_component.

  " Create type descriptors
  go_structdescr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>create( gt_component ).
  go_tabledescr ?= cl_abap_tabledescr=>create( go_structdescr ).

  " Create usable variables
  CREATE DATA gr_range TYPE HANDLE go_tabledescr.
  ASSIGN gr_range->* TO <gs_range>.

  CREATE DATA gr_range_line TYPE HANDLE go_structdescr.
  ASSIGN gr_range_line->* TO <gs_range_line>.
```